# Asp.Net Running a content page using master page error > TemplateContainer(typeof(MySite.MasterPage))

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2015, master-pages, .net-4.6.2

I created an empty asp.net web application > `.Net 4.6.2` in `VS 2015`
I added a simple master page & a simple content page on this project.
When i open content page in browser i get the **error** below :

> Line 174:        [TemplateContainer(typeof(Panel.Site1))]

[image: TemplateContainer Error]

What this error mean & how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name of your project or namespaces conflicting with ASP.NET form authentification class name: `System.Web.Security.FormsAuthentication`. According to me you are missing namespace name or any required reference.

Comment: My project's name is : Panel

Comment: I renamed my project's name > Solved > Thanks